# eclipse equinox: how to set return value?

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point, equinox

How to set the return value of a Java application started via Eclipse Equinox? It implements `IApplication`. I see that the `start()` method has an argument of type `IApplicationContext`, which provides a `setResultValue()` method. But this value is an Object, not an Integer.  I searched the Internet for an example of its use but could not find one.

What would happen if our application simply calles `exit()`?

In my current understanding, the return value of a Java application is either the argument of `exit()`, if that is called, or else the return value of `main()`.  This return value is available after the application exits, which happens either if `exit()` is called or else if tha application's last thread terminates.

Our application is started from within Eclipse and as standalone tool (in GUI and batch mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of doing this is the return value of the `IApplication` `start` method:

```
@Override
public Object start(IApplicationContext context)
{
   ... run the application

  return Integer.valueOf(0);
}
```

Although the return value can be any `Object` it is usual to return an `Integer`.

The `IApplication` object already defines a few exit values for your `EXIT_OK`, `EXIT_RESTART` and `EXIT_RELAUCH`:

```
public static final Integer EXIT_OK = new Integer(0);

public static final Integer EXIT_RESTART = new Integer(23);

public static final Integer EXIT_RELAUNCH = new Integer(24);
```

Comment: Well, we need additional return values.  And they should be different from the three pre-defined.  Unfortunately, the JavaDoc does not tell which Integer is associated with which constant

Comment: As far as I can see you can use any Integer value you want. I have added the predefined values

Comment: I copied them directly from the `IApplication` interface. What class are you looking at?

Comment: You are right. I removed my comment shortly after posting it. But you seem to have seen it anyways. At least I don't see it anymore